# class file for redis.clients.jedis.JedisShardInfo not found

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis

when I upgrade the jedis to version 4.2.3 in gradle.build:

```
    api "redis.clients:jedis:4.2.3"
```

show error:

```
/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/retire/dolphin-common/src/main/java/misc/config/redis/RedisConfig.java:77: error: cannot access JedisShardInfo
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisConfig);
               ^
  class file for redis.clients.jedis.JedisShardInfo not found
```

this is the redis config:

```
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        var redisConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);
        redisConfig.setPassword(redisPwd);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisConfig);
    }
```

why did this error happen? what should I do to fix it? I have searched from google seems no one facing this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class `JedisShardInfo` is removed since Jedis 4.

> The ShardedJedisPool, Sharded, ShardedJedis, BinaryShardedJedis, ShardInfo, JedisShardInfo classes have been removed.

Here is [the list of all breaking changes between Jedis 3.x and Jedis 4.x](https://github.com/redis/jedis/blob/master/docs/3to4.md).

Comment: ok, but why newest spring-data-redis 2.6.4 JedisConnectionFactory, still uses `JedisShardInfo` ... ?

error: cannot access JedisShardInfo
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(connectionConfig);

Answer (score 3):

Use this dependency 3.9.0 or less version, because Some of the classes have been removed in the new version.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Note:** SNAPSHOT, M1, M2, M3, and M4 releases typically WORK IN PROGRESS. The Spring team is still working on them, Recommend NOT using them.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the classes have been removed,
so use Jedis version: 3.9.0

Answer (score 0):

change the verion as per below

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.redis.sprinboot</groupId>
<artifactId>redis-springboot-mysql</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>redis-springboot-mysql</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
```